# Check Whether Directory Exists In Remote Server For Perl

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I wish to check whether a path given is exists or is a directory in another site server in Perl. My code is as below.

```
my $destination_path = "<path>";
my $ssh = "usr/bin/ssh";
my $user_id = getpwuid( $< );
my $site = "<site_name>";
my $host = "rsync.$site.com";

if ($ssh $user_id\@$host [-d $destination_path]){
  print "Is a directory.\n";
}
else{
  print "Is not a directory.\n";
}
```

I am sure my code is wrong as I modify the code according to bash example I see from another question but I have no clue how to fix it. Thanks for everyone that helps here.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention what the problem is. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Is it as simple having `usr/bin/ssh` where I suspect you want `/usr/bin/ssh`?

Comment: Hi. @DaveCross The problem of my code is not working for checking whether the directory exists or not in the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is the name of a command, and it must be separated from other words on the command line. So just use more spaces:

```
$ssh $user\@$host [ -d $destination_path ]
```

To actually execute this command, you'll want to use the builtin [`system`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#system) function. `system` returns 0 when the command it executes is successful (see the docs at the link)

```
if (0 == system("$ssh $user\@$host [ -d $destination_path ]")) {
    print "Is a directory.\n";
} else {
    print "Is not a directory.\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The answer is working. May I ask how can I create directory for the path if it is not a directory? I have tried `system("$ssh $user\@$host [ mkdir -p $destination_path ]")` but it don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the remote file system through SFTP:

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("rsync.$site.com");
if ($sftp->test_d($destination_path)) {
    "print $destination_path is a directory!\n";
}
```